# Javascript - Array Element Disappearing

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a global array that I'm trying to fill with objects. The first object I am inserting is being kept as a separate variable as well, and created via the return of a function.

However, once I add it to the empty array, the array lists index 0 as being null. Despite this, logging the object at index 0 returns the proper object.

Here's the relevant code:

```
var triangles;

function makePoint(x, y) {
    var point = { x : x, y : y };
    return point;
}

function makeTriangle(p1, p2, p3) {
    var triangle = { p1 : p1, p2 : p2, p3 : p3 };
    return triangle;
}

function makeSupertriangle(sizeX, sizeY) {
    return makeTriangle(makePoint(-1 * sizeX, sizeY), makePoint(sizeX, sizeY), makePoint((sizeX / 2), -1 * sizeY));
}


function triangulate(points, sizeX, sizeY) {
    triangles = [];

    var supertriangle = makeSupertriangle(sizeX, sizeY);
    triangles[0] = supertriangle;

    console.log(triangles);
    console.log(triangles[0]);

    //...
}

triangulate([], 60, 40);
```

The log is showing:

```
[Object]
0: null
length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]

Object {p1: Object, p2: Object, p3: Object}
p1: Object
p2: Object
p3: Object
__proto__: Object
```

Does anybody know why the object isn't properly showing up in the array but can still be accessed from it?

I created a Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bPgn5/)

Comment: I cannot reproduce. I defined sizeX = 5, sizeY = 5 and copied your code in the Chrome console. Worked fine, it logged your object, not as null.

Comment: me neither, works fine in chrome console..

Comment: I can't think of any information I'm leaving out. triangles is declared globally but not initialized. The code after the functions is all inside a function triangulate(points, sizeX, sizeY) { ... }

Comment: I have no problems creating it...what do you set in sizeX and sizeY?

Comment: Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zvavY/) with your code as posted. It works fine in Chrome. Play around with the fiddle until you work out what broke it and also let us know what browser you are using. It even works if you pass in `null`, `undefined` or `NaN`.

Comment: They're just integer numbers. The logs for triangles[0] are getting appropriate point values with those numbers, but the array isn't containing the object properly. Using Chrome.

Comment: @Swcompto: Do you see the same thing with the fiddle I posted?

Comment: It's working properly in the fiddle. I updated it to represent the fact that triangles is global and the code is inside a function, but it still worked. Still not working on my page though.